# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) Strapi

Tags: digital-ocean, strapi, aws-codecommit

I have recently migrated my database from AWS to Digital Ocean and I'm facing an issue with my Strapi application (not sure if it's related to the migration or not).

While I can successfully run Strapi locally and access the admin panel and DB without any problems, I encounter a 502 Bad Gateway error when trying to connect to take my application live. My repo is saved in AWS code commit. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

After I run the app locally, I use the command pm2 start ecosystem.config.js to restart the server but a 502 Error still shows.

[image]